# Android - Adding Last item in the end of a list ListView

Tags: android, listview

I am having a custom list view. In general it shows some 5-6 data depending to the data. i want a small message in the end of a ListView saying "End of list of results". How to achieve that?

Comment: Hi Adarsh, are you using ListView or RecyclerView?
If Listview, then you can add footer by using [lv.addFooterView()] (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#addFooterView(android.view.View, java.lang.Object, boolean)) method

Comment: hi karan! I am using List View

Comment: Use this method here- https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#addFooterView(android.view.View)

Comment: Thanks @Karan!! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `addFooterView` method of ListView.